# PHP FastCGI/XML/DOM Configure

Tags: php, fastcgi, php5

Guys, any ideas why when I configure PHP 5.3.1, these options fail?

```
Notice: Following unknown configure options were used:

--with-xml
--with-dom
--enable-fastcgi
--enable-discard-path
--enable-force-cgi-redirect
```

Answer (score 1):

Because these options are not used in PHP 5.3.